# Time series frequency in 5 minutes timestamps

Tags: python, r, arrays

I have two large time series data. Both is separated by 5minutes intervals timestamp. The length of each time series is 3month from(August 1 2014 to October 2014). I’m using R (3.1.1) for forecasting the data. I’d like to know the value of the “frequency” argument in the ts() function in R, for each data set. Since most of the examples and cases I’ve seen so far are for months or days at the most, it is quite confusing for me when dealing with equally separated 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it would be either of these:

```r
myts1 <- ts(series, frequency = (60*60*24)/5)
myts2 <- ts(series, deltat = 5/(60*60*24))
```

In the first, the frequency argument gives the number of times sampled per time unit. If time unit is the day, there are 60*60*24 seconds per day and you're sampling every 5 of them, so you would be sampling 17280 times per day.  Alternatively, the second option is what fraction of a day separates each sample.  Here, we would say that every 5.787037e-05 of a day, a sample is drawn.  If the time unit is something different (e.g., the hour), then obviously these would change